# azuredevops rest api: get commits for a push is always returning 0

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

we are using "pushes" API feature of Azure devops link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples

the response of the get push call has a hyperlink to the "commits" associated with that push, example below.

"commits": {
"href": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/pushes/23/commits"
}

Now this url irrespective of the pushid always returns the following,
{
"count": 0,
"value": []
}

ideally its should the commits associated with the push, is this a bug in ADO ?

we cross checked the following

1. repo is correct
2. pushid is correct

Thanks -Nen

Comment: Can you provide more context? What tool are you using to test your API call? Do you have a script to replicate the behavior you are seeing? I just tested this using the browser I'm logged in to Azure DevOps, using a URL like this: `https://dev.azure.com/[AzDoOrganization]/_apis/git/repositories/[RepoId]/pushes/[PushId]?api-version=6.0` and it worked fine. How did you get the Repo Id? One way to get it is to navigate to the Project Settings > Repositories and then click the Repo you want to query. The Id appears in the URL.

Comment: i am using postman, i got the rep0 id by listing the repositories using the api, i confirmed that by cross checking in the project settings.

Comment: your link does not include the "commits" after the pushid 
 https://dev.azure.com/[AzDoOrganization]/_apis/git/repositories/[RepoId]/pushes/[PushId]/commits?api-version=6.0

Comment: You are correct, I now verified with a URL like this: `https://dev.azure.com/[AzDoOrganization]/_apis/git/repositories/[RepoId]/pushes/[PushId]/commits` and again, it worked fine. The value array contains the commits that are visible in the push. Just a check: did you verify if you can access the commits using the user account you used to create the Personal Access Token to authenticate? Using a URL like this: `https://dev.azure.com/[AzDoOrganization]/[TeamProjectName]/_git/[RepoName]/pushes/[PushId]?_a=commits`? And what scopes are assigned to the Personal Access Token you are using?

Comment: i am an admin and i have configured all "Full Access" for testing

Comment: Can you execute the PowerShell [script](https://gist.github.com/FokkoVeegens/b3db425079f3fe03bfc77278d6bc1f9f) I wrote for you to check if that works? It will perform the same calls we discussed above. Please change the first five lines to match your situation.